# リストの中身との照合

Tags: python

以下のようなタプルが含まれたリストがある時、`('akira','2001-09-23')` がlist内に存在することを確認したいのですが、下記のコードではtrueが返ってこないのはなぜでしょうか。
どなたか教えて頂けますと幸いです。

**対象のリスト:**

```
list = [('akira', '2001-09-23'), ('kenta', '1992-08-15'), ('yuko', '1975-04-30')]
```

**試したコード:**

```
print(['akira','2001-09-23'] in list)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

リストの中身はタプルなので以下のとおりにするとTrueが返ってくるはずです

```
print(('akira','2001-09-23') in list)
```